# Improving Wine startup time

Tags: wine

I'm running Wine 5.0 on a relatively fast CPU (i5-8250U) and a SSD.
When I start any MS Windows program for the first time after login, there's a 3 second waiting period, even with a small executable like PuTTY.
Once Wine has started for the first time, the same or any other small executable (like IrfanView for example) will start within 200-500ms, which is almost as fast as on native Windows. So it seems like the whole Wine environment is cached once it has been called for the first time.

Is there any way to preload this environment upon startup to speedup the loading process?
I've tried adding `wineserver -p` to the startup process, but that didn't change the 3s waiting period.

Here are some atop values when starting WinSCP:

`PID SYSCPU USRCPU  VGROW   RGROW ST EXC  THR  S CPUNR  CPU CMD

 4265  0.49s  0.95s   2.6G  85540K N-   -    3  S     0  16% WinSCP.exe
 4148  0.71s  0.46s 15660K      0K --   -    1  S     1  12% wineserver
 4152  0.55s  0.51s     0K      0K NE   0    0  E     -  11% <winebuil>`

Comment: Did you know there is `ssh` for Gnu/Linux and MacOS? Like PuTTY, but better. And debian has a putty package.

Comment: During those 3 seconds is there high CPU/disk/network usage?

Comment: I've added some atop values. There's no network traffic.